# excel color format through VB 6

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a VB 6 application. I need to color a Excel work sheet which I have created through that application. I know the range iof the cells but i dont know how to do it.Can any one help me out?
Thankx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know VB6, but I can tell how it works for VBA and probably its similar.

```
Range("A1:A2").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

with `.Interior` you get the background of the range and with `.Color` you can set an RGB value

Comment: This aint working I have tried! It throws an error "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' Falied"

Comment: I use this within an Excel Worksheet, I think if you use it from VB6 you need to give also the worksheet object and also on which sheet this range is, something like: `_WorksheetObject_._Sheet_.Range("A1:A2").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)`

Comment: You can find here a brief tutorial on Excel with VB6. Maybe this will help you: [Tutorial/FAQ: How to Automate Excel from VB6 (or VB5/VBA)](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=391665)

Comment: No Help. The keyword "Range" is not being accepted somehow. I will hace to scrap the application code it seems!

Comment: Have you had a look into the tutorial I linked in my last comment? According to this you should be able to use the Range Object on a Sheet Object.